# Module not found: Can't resolve Next.js - TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, next.js

> I receive the image´s error but I don´t understand why do I get it.
> Also attached the directory in the second image.

[image]

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ProductModel } from '../models/product';
import { CardProduct } from '../components/CardProduct';

const List = () => {

  let list: ProductModel[] = [  //ProductModel[] esto significa que va a ser un array de ProductModel
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "shoes",
      price: 9999,
    },
  ];

  const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductModel[]>(list);

  return (
    <div>
      Soy la página de Productos
      {products.map((element, index) => {
        return <CardProduct product={element}/>;
      })}
      <br/>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>Ir a la home</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

[image]

Comment: Often times, a restart of dev server tends to fix this. Can you try that?

Comment: I did but not worked

Comment: In addition to restarting your dev server, try deleting the `.next` folder from the root of the project.

Comment: @GCB Any further updates on how you could solve this issue?

Comment: @PsyGik What else would you try here. This happened to me after I was changing the components from js to tsx

Comment: Damn nextjs, this is a big problem, try deleting .next folder wont work

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck in a similar issue after removing a `loading.tsx` file on Next.js 13 with App router. The solution was to **remove the `.next/` directory**, which will be automatically rebuild on `npm run dev`.

Comment: This is the fix that worked for me. Thanks! I was cracking my head over running `nx reset` or manually nuking the cache at `./node_modules/.cache/nx` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an empty `tsconfig.json` file in your project's root folder and then run npm as you would normally (for instance, `npm run dev`). NextJs will then populate the file with default ts config values. See here:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens due to missing properties in tsconfig.json. Try creating a new tsconfig.json and let nextjs generate the required config for you.

```
touch tsconfig.json
```

For ref: https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/typescript/create-tsconfig

Answer (score 2):

For me, it had to do with Module Aliases. I had to update my `tsconfig.json` to have the following:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
  "@/types/*": ["types/*"],
  "@/lib/*": ["lib/*"], //any other root-level paths
}
```

As others have mentioned, it may be useful to remove the `.next/` directory, which will be automatically rebuilt on `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I had a jsconfig.json file so I copied only paths from compiler options from that file and pasted it to the tsconfig.json compiler options file this solved my problem. If it works then you can also delete jsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the tsconfig.json file was missing:

`"baseUrl": ".",`